can i run python codebase with endpint in dataiku periodically
I have a repo that can contain multiple modules, but has an end point, "main.py", and that end point is able to run the whole workflow.
whole workflow does bunch of things from example read data from the database persist on disk and  and then the persisted files are processed in parallel using Dask and does ML inference and then results are written back to database. whole things i can accomplish just by running
python main.py
For the workflow design, I am using Prefect.
Is it possible to run the entire codebase in Dataiku similar to prefect?

This is total unclear question. Can you clarify more detail?

i have tried to add more clarification let me if it helps

Please take a look what a MRE is (and other related).

For my understanding you do not need any orchestration tool. Just run the script. this could be done in many ways. But you do not need any overhead that dataiku or prefect will introduce just a container and machine to execute it

i need a orchestration tool specifically Dataiku, because i need to run this periodically. i am able to do this using prefect but but its hard to manage hence looking if i can do the orchestration in Dataiku
